# Link in a DataRow (Datatable)

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, datarow

I'm building a DataTable dynamically and I'm trying to add a "link" in the DataRow(s) that I'm adding to the DataTable. The DataTable is bound to a GridView after it's creation.

Something like that :

```
   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col"));

        row["col"] = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link here</a>";

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }
```

Then I bind it to a GridView :

```
        <asp:GridView ID="grdView" Runat="server" border="0" EnableViewState="true" style="width:100%;"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="false" PagerSettings-Visible="false" 
            ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="true" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"
            Visible="True">
        </asp:GridView>
```

But the HTML in the Column is encoded when I bind it to the GridView.
Is there a way to add a HyperLink object there or something like that?

P.S. It's not in the example but the columns are added dynamically (it means that I don't know before the rendering how many columns I'll have)

**UPDATE #1**

I have access to the GridView when I create the columns.
I was able to do something like that :

```
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col"));

    BoundField bf = new BoundField();
    bf.HtmlEncode = false;
    bf.DataField = "col";
    grd.Columns.Add(bf);

   row["col"] = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link here</a>";
```

But it displays 2 coloumns "col"...

**UPDATE #3 :**
I used a DataGrid instead. It doesn't encode HTML when inserted in "plain text" in the data rows.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning html code from your query, just use `htmlEncode=False` on your boundfield. Also set AutoGenerateColumns="false" on your gridview, that's why you're getting double columns on your gridview.

Comment: Yep, this is all that was needed.  And to actually have a `BoundField` in the GridView:  `<asp:BoundField DataField="URL" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="URL" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="URL">
        <ItemStyle Width="25% />
    </asp:BoundField>`

Answer (score 1):

It's been an long time since this was asked, but I arrived here being one of the first google results, so I would like to tell you that I have resolved this adding a "HyperLinkField":

```
HyperLinkField myLink = new HyperLinkField();
myLink.HeaderText = "Link Here";
myLink.DataTextField = "Click here";
myLink.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" };
myLink.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "NewPage.aspx?id={0}&otherId={1}&otherId2={2}";

myGridView.Columns.Add(myLink);

//Finally bind the data...
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry disregard...I didnt see the dynamic table constraint
Why do you add a template column to the GridView and then add a hyperlink. Sorry this code wont seem to format correctly in this space

```
    <asp:TemplateColumn>                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypLink" Text="test" Target='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moved_ref_amt").ToString() %>'></asp:HyperLink>                                                                        </ItemTemplate>                                                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I get "templatecolumn" is not a known element. Are you sure it's working with a grid view?

Comment: Its template field in gridview,  it was template column in data grid

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="X">    <ItemTemplate>                                                       </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

Comment: It works, but for the first column only, and since I don't know how many columns I'll have, I don't know if it could work?

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a GridView_RowDataBound event which allow you to dynamically inject controls in to rows, format the content, etc.

You will have access to the table's row element (DataItem) and will be able to parse that and format the grid row as you need.

For a good intro example see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx?ppud=4

Edit: You are getting duplicate columns because you have `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` as well as the template for the column.