# Add a hyperlink to a datatable / gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find a suitable answer.

I'm creating a datatable dynamically and using this to populate a web control gridview...

I'm wondering if or how to change 1 column (URL) to be a hyperlink?

My code for creating the datatable:

```
private DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn myDataColumn;

    myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
    myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Title";
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

    myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
    myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    myDataColumn.ColumnName = "URL";

    myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);
.
.
.
}
```

I'm adding to the datatable as follows:

```
private void AddDataToTable(string title, string strLink......
        {
            DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
            row["Title"] = title;
            row["URL"] = strLink;
            .
            .
            .
```

then binding the datatable to the gridview:

```
datagrid.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["myDatatable"]).DefaultView;

datagrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: So it's asp.net, isn't it ? I added the corresponding tags.

Comment: @digemAll, Yeah cheers..

Comment: Similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109021/link-in-a-datarow-datatable

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't do this in the Datatable - that's just an in-memory representation of the data. It doesn't hold anything about the column types in the grid view.

Once it's in a DataGridView, just set the column type to [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx).

Comment: Oh - try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) one instead then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
row["URL"] = "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>";
```

But then you should use a BoundField on your GridView, and set `HtmlEncode="false"`:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="URL" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="URL" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="URL">
    <ItemStyle Width="25% />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

when u bind to a gridview or Detail view, U can add hyperlink control to the url column(Template field) and set

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL")%>'
```

OR

if u wanna navigate to another website like Google, set

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://{0}", Eval("URL")) %>'
```

... :)

Comment: I haven't defined the columns of the gridview in asp as they change and the gridview is being built in the code...

Comment: @Standage I am not quite sure what ur saying. Correct me if I am wrong, if you use visual studio wizard to bind the data to a grid view, the wizard will automatically create bound field. however, u can convert that bound fields into a template filed and then u can add hyperlink control into that template field.

Comment: I'm not using visual studio wizard to bind the data to a gridview, I'm creating a datatable with contents as above in code and then setting this to be the grid views datasource.

Comment: you means your are not using Itemtemplate in Gridview?you want to setting in Datatable?